# WebStorm 2016.2 + Reactor Starter kit + Getting Started Tutorial

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

Apologies for such a newbies question. I've spent several hours googling but no luck yet on my issue.

I've WebStorm 2016.2. I'm going through the very simple '[getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)' tutorial for React. I cannot figure out how to Create a Configuration to run the 'helloworld.html' file from that tutorial with the React Starter Kit 'new project' in WebStorm. I'd appreciate some guidance.

I've downloaded and installed npm (windows 10) and that's working from the command prompt.

Many thanks. My background is in python so this new JS world is proving fiddly.

Comment: not the answer to your question, but I think this is a better way to start https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html

Comment: Yes, am thinking this might be wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to follow Dauren Akibekov's advice and simply walk through this tutorial (and worry about WebStorm much later) https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html